# HTTP Client to TCP Server (C#)

Tags: c#, httpclient, tcpclient, tcplistener, networkstream

I am not receiving the Content posted by the HTTPClient but I can read the other information such as Content-Length and other headers. Let me explain the code here:

Here is the Server Code :

```
 TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),1234);
tcpListener.Start()//Start the listener and wait for client to connect.
while(true)
{
 TcpClient newclient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient(); // calls the readdata everytime a post is put in the specified URL - done by client below.
 ReadData(newClient)
}

public void ReadData(TcpClient newclient)
{
            byte[] buffer = new byte[50];
            Stream ns = newclient.GetStream();     
            ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Console.WriteLine( Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
 }
Sample Server Output :


 Received JSON DATA POST /MovieData HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:3291
Content-Length: 48
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive - But the Content is missing. I am not sure why. I tried to extend the buffer size but still Content Length and other info is posted but content is missing.
```

Here is the Client  Code :
Client keeps sending message "Sending Request in a loop

```
                    HttpClient ModifyClient = new HttpClient();
                    ModifyClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:1234/MovieData");
                    while(true)
                   {                        
    
                    ModifyClient.PostAsync(ModifyClient.BaseAddress
                                   , new StringContent("SendingRequest",Encoding.UTF8));
                   }
```

I am able to receive the post message as shown in the server for every post but what is missing is that is the string content that is actually sent "SendingRequest" text. The other header properties are there.
Is it some configuration that I am missing while using the HttpClient ?

Comment: You need to read the stream until its actual end. You seem to only read 50 bytes(?) and then drop the rest and wait for next connection. Also: Are you really wanting to implement the entire HTTP protocol yourself? I'd suggest to use something more suitable that does that kind of protocol handling for you.

Comment: And you may want to NOT do a DOS attack on your own server ... `while(true) {                         ModifyClient.PostAsync(ModifyClient.BaseAddress ... `

Comment: @Fildor I tried to read the end of the stream by increasing the buffer size to 1024 but there is nothing in it . I am designing the server with TCP to keep the server performance optimal. But, Have i done anything incomplete that causes the content to be not available?

Comment: @Fildor  I am creating a post request every 5 sec for the server to read. I have a not put in while loop . I am trigger that method every 5 sec.

Comment: @Fildor : One more detail might help,  is there a way to use HttpClient to keep loading the data without dropping the Connection once the connection is established

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is serveral issues in your server:
Missing Semicolon:

```
tcpListener.Start()//Start the listener and wait for client to connect.
```

newclient vs newClient and missing semicolon after ReadData()

```
TcpClient newclient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient(); // calls the readdata everytime a post is put in the specified URL - done by client below.
            ReadData(newClient)
```

The second issue is, that you are using HTTPClient to connect to a TCP-Server, you should use TCPClient and send a STREAM (this is what you expect!)

```
         TcpClient client = new TcpClient("/127.0.0.1", 1234);
         string message = "myMessage";
         // Translate message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array
         Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

         // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
         NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

         // Send the message to the connected TcpServer.
         stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
using System.Net;

var client = new HttpClient()
{
    DefaultRequestVersion =  HttpVersion.Version30,
    DefaultVersionPolicy = HttpVersionPolicy.RequestVersionExact
};

Console.WriteLine("--- Localhost:5001 ---");
HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:5001/");
string body = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(
    $"status: {resp.StatusCode}, version: {resp.Version}, " +
    $"body: {body.Substring(0, Math.Min(100, body.Length))}");
```

refrence : [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-http3)

or : [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example)

final refrence : [socket-example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-tcp-services)

Comment: Well, I do not have the HttpVersion.Version30 , the latest version that I have is Version11.
Also, I would like to read the Post made by HttpClient via Tcpclient object.